# How to select only the first elements satisfying a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop, ansi-sql

I have the following table (simplification of the real problem):

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | T     |
|  2 | T     |
|  3 | F     |
|  4 | T     |
+----+-------+
```

Now a simple `SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value='T';` would get me all the IDs where value is T, but I just need, in the example above, the first 2 (1 and 2).

What is the best way to do this? I'd prefer not to use a while loop.

I tagged it MySQL, but a solution working for most database engines would be better.

Edit: based on the answers, I probably wasn't clear enough:
I only want the first IDs where value is 'T'. This can be anything from no values to all values.

Edit 2: another example:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | F     |
|  2 | T     |
|  5 | T     |
|  6 | F     |
|  7 | T     |
|  9 | T     |
+----+-------+
```

The result would be [].

Example 3:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | T     |
|  2 | T     |
|  5 | T     |
|  6 | F     |
|  7 | T     |
|  9 | T     |
+----+-------+
```

And the result: [1, 2, 5]

Comment: I've updated my answer with your updated requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something as simple as this? just limiting the result?

```
select id from table where value = 'T' order by id asc limit 2
```

Just change the order to `desc` instead of `asc` if for some reason you want the last two matches, instead of the first two.

I see the criteria has changed a little.

```
select id
  from `table` t
    where t.id >= (select @min := min(id) from `table` t2 where value = 'T') 
      and not exists (select id from `table` t3 where value = 'F' and id > @min and id < t.id)
   and value = 'T'
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed50f/7)

If you want no results when the first value is 'F', then this one:

```
select id
  from `table` t
    where 
       not exists (select id from `table` t3 where value = 'F' and id < t.id)
   and value = 'T'
```

Comment: i don't think he needs to sort or order

Comment: Without ordering, the 'first two' has no meaning. And since he specifically asked for the values with the lowest id, sorting is appropriate

Comment: I assume the id would be auto increment since we set default value of PK as auto incremented.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo - Even if the PK is an AUTOINCREMENT field, there is still no ***guarantee*** of which rows will be returned by `LIMIT 2` without also using `ORDER BY`.  It is true that in reality you *normally* get the results in PK order, but there is *no guarantee*.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo read this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,239471,239688#msg-239688. if you want order, you must use `order by`, otherwise while it might look to work, there is the potential that it will stop

Comment: That's nearly what I wanted. If the first element has a value of 'F', then the result should be [].

Comment: Oh, you only want a result if the first result is 'T' ?

Comment: @Burkhard there you go. only when the first result is T do you get any results.

Comment: Isn't the *current* version of the question even simpler than that?  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <= COALESCE((SELECT MIN(id)-1 FROM table WHERE value = 'F'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table))`  *(Two scalar sub-queries rather than a correlated sub-query)*

Comment: It probably is but by the 15th variation of the question I was happy enough with the results of the frankenquery

Answer (score 1):

If Ids are auto-incremented then `order by` `limit` could be used

```
select * from table_name where value = 'T' order by id limit 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edit. I probably wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Could you provide some more example, if I understood correctly from the given example `1,2` are saving `T` then `3` is 'F' followed by `4` with `T` so as soon as it reaches 3 with a different value it should stop is that what you are looking at ? And if so what happens if you have `5` with `T` and so on ?

Comment: @pala_ if the ids are repeating then its fairly clear i.e. first id with value `T` but if they are not repeating then perhaps this needs revisit.

Comment: my interpretation is he wants the first window of T values, wherever it occurs.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: yes. I want the first N values of 'id' where value is 'T'.

Comment: @Burkhard then look below. the answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LIMIT 2` as below

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table 
WHERE value='T'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any order or sorting in the data

```
  SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value='T' limit 0,2
```

You might need to add 'ORDER BY' if you want to order by id. e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value='T' order by id limit 0,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the id of the first occurrence of 'F' then use in a condition.
You could do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM tables where id < (select AVG(id) FROM tables WHERE value = 'F' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: What is you *intent* in using `AVG(id)`?  What if the tables has three records at the end that are `F`?  Say id's 98, 99 and 100.  The `AVG(id)` returns 99, which means that your outer query will include row 98, which if a `F` and the OP and wants `T`s.  This doesn't seem to make any sense to me at all.

Comment: What if the records are `{F, F, F, T, T}`?  Then your query returns the first `F` and none of the `T`s...

Comment: @MatBailie, That is why the record limits only to 1, I simply just assume that query returns a collection even if there is only 1 record. I am not saying that getting the average of ids is the right way though. There may be a better way but the idea is get the id and use in a condition.

Comment: Aggregates are applied *after* the `WHERE` but ***before*** the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`.  So, you *are* getting the average id of ***all*** `F` records.